# Setting up the GDM Theme

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, gdm

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Classic (no effects) and because of the fact that some system options have disappeared with the new system release I've been struggling with this for a while and despite this seems very easy I can't do this :/ - does anyone know how to choose a GDM Theme? I'm quite sure that GDM is now in use on my Ubuntu - I set it up with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Despite I moved the theme folder to `/usr/share/gdm/themes` nothing has changed by now, I've logged out and in a couple of times but everytime I get the standard log in window and wallpaper (different from mine).

So I'll appreciate any kind of help from anybody, now I have absolutely no idea how to figure it out.
Cheers.

Comment: Ubuntu-Tweak doesn't alter GDM, only LightDM.

Comment: Not sure if this is still a problem, but I think it is a configuration problem. Have you tried gdm3setup?

Answer (score 1):

Try Ubuntu Tweak, it will let you choose themes and configure much more.

Just go to http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ and click the link "Download Now" to install

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - unfortunately the "startup" section is missing and i can't find anything about "startup" on Ubuntu Tweak website. I can see it now on youtube on some people's Ubuntu Tweak tutorial. A plugin missing?

Comment: Sorry haven't seen the gdm part of your problem. Why not install other login manager like Slim? Or remove and reinstall gdm.